# Need Suggestion for Magento christmas extension [snow fall]

Tags: magento

I am trying to decorate my magento website with decorations for Christmas and New year. Is there a free extension for the Christmas decorations?

Thanks..

Comment: Try this http://store.velanapps.com/holiday-effects
Has features like snow fall, santa claus etc.,

Comment: @KeyurShah I want to add all effects like santa clause, Christmas tree, snow and much more. But the extension from you having only snow effect. But i will tell thanks to introduce that extension to me. Sorry for delayed accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is one free extension available for decoration

http://www.magestore.com/website-decorative-effect.html

but i am not sure how look like this because I haven't used it,